# Raspberry Pi connect to lcd monitor/ webcam

Tags: gpio, pi-3

I have a pi3 and I want to connect it to my monitor that came from my old computer. The problem is that it is a monitor and a webcam combined, and the cable is too wide for the connectors. I was wondering if I could use the gpio pins, and if so, which ones and how to connect it all. *[http://imgur.com/hu5vKI9](https://imgur.com/hu5vKI9)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the raspberry pi supports the following directly

- hdmi via the hdmi connector (video + audio)
- composite video over 3.5 mm jack (video + audio)

indirectly

- smaller screens such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CNJVG8K) one over gpio pins
- here is a [GPIO to VGA](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/gert-vga-adapter/) converter as well (not sure if it is commercially available though)

To answer your question, you need to share the details of the supported connector(s) (could share a photo) on your monitor without which it is impossible to suggest a working solution. see [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=83446) page for details on video out options

Comment: It is the kind of connector you see at the end of a ribbon cable. I cannot share a photo, because I do not have enough reputation. It is wider than the connector ports on the board.

Comment: @user6929543 can you share link to the monitor model ? if you find you are note allowed to post links, type in the link as plain text surrounded by back ticks

Comment: I don't know the monitor model. I literally pulled it out of a broken laptop. I will post a link to a pic though.

Comment: If it is a salvaged part, odds are its not designed to be used in the way you wish to. you are probably better off going with a standard display.

Comment: If it's from a laptop, it's probably [FPD-Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FPD-Link); the Pi has no compatible connector for this.